# The diff between openssl-2 and openssl-3

Tags: version, openssl

New to this.

How can you tell what the openssl version is and what's the diff?

Answer (score 3):

Find the current [OpenSSL](http://openssl.org/) version on the [OpenSSL webpage](http://openssl.org/) (0.9.8k as of 25-Mar-2009 and 1.0.0, third beta as of 15-Jul-2009). OpenSSL is a implementation of the [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) cryptographic protocol suite (amongst other things).